# Нужно узнать ip адрес своего компьютера в интернете в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В документации нашел `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`. Но у меня выдает ошибку. Не работает `gethostbyname`, не знаю почему. Версия питона 3.2. Подскажите, из-за чего может не работать или другое решение поставленной задачи.

Comment: ip адрес чего?

Comment: компьютера в интернете

Comment: это очевидно, какого именно? Вашего? Если да, то какое у вас подключение, через роутер? Покажите код.

Comment: да моего.
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

Comment: Я не случайно спросил про подключение. Ваш код работает и выдает вполне ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @dword, этот код будет работать только в том случае, если для текущей системы установлен `hostname`, который резольвиться во внешний `ip`. Хотя с тем же успехом он может отрезольвится в приватный `ip` или даже в loopback, все зависит от используемого DNS сервера.

Comment: именно так

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> import http.client
>>> conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("ifconfig.me")
>>> conn.request("GET", "/ip")
>>> conn.getresponse().read()
'123.45.67.89\n'
```

Comment: В Python 3 `httplib` был переименован в `http.client`.

Comment: проделал действия. в итоге получил b'92.112.201.134\n' не могли бы вы описать как это все работает.

Comment: Все предельно просто. Сервис [ifconfig.me](http://ifconfig.me/) по запросу [http://ifconfig.me/ip](http://ifconfig.me/ip) выдает ip адрес текущего запроса.

Answer (score 6):

Внешний адрес можно определить через специально для этого предназначенный протокол [STUN (*Session Traversal Utilities for NAT*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN):

```
$ pip3 install --user pystun3
```

```
>>> import stun
>>> stun.get_ip_info()
('Full Cone', '2.94.28.157', 54320)
```

Показывает внешний адрес и пробрасывает UDP порт.

Comment: it works. Let's see how long the project lasts.

Comment: @jfs стун серверов много сейчас, они будут жить пока есть ip4)

Comment: дело не в том будет ли протокол жить. К примеру, http протокол будет жить ещё долго. Вопрос в том сколько времени будет жить конкретный сервис, проект. (я был удивлён, что `http ifconfig.me/ip` до cих пор работает). На родительском проекте не видно активности: https://github.com/jtriley/pystun Ясно ли кто поддерживает stun-сервера из этого кода? Есть ли уверенность, что они продолжат работу?

Comment: @jfs там стоит несколько публичных серверов, которые живы уже лет 15-20. Насчет того что код не двигается - там некуда развиваться. Это всего одна функция.

Comment: `pystun` (без 3) приводит к `TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable` при вызове `stun.get_ip_info()`. `pystun3` пока работает на Python 3.8. `pynat`  также работает.

Comment: @jfs потому что он для питона 2, потому я и указал 3

Comment: установка и импорт проходят без ошибок на Питоне 3. Там несколько PR c поддержкой Python 3 https://github.com/jtriley/pystun/pulls (по сути пару крошечных функций поправить достаточно, чтобы заработало, если бы проект поддерживался)

Comment: автору похоже не интересно, да и ладно. есть приличный форк, тут скорее надо связаться с автором и освободить имя в PyPI . А для энтерпрайза прощё 2 байта переслать на чистом socket.socket

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы узнать свой публичный IP адрес, можно DNS запрос сделать, например на Windows:

```
C:\> nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

Вот [несколько примеров кода как на Питоне DNS запрос можно сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075729/4279).

```
$ python3 -m pip install aiodns
$ python3 -m asyncio
>>> import aiodns
>>> resolver = aiodns.DNSResolver()
>>> resolver.nameservers = "208.67.222.222", "208.67.220.220"
>>> (await resolver.query("myip.opendns.com", "A"))[0].host
'192.0.2.2'
```

Достоинства DNS по сравнению с HTTP, чтобы свой внешний IP адрес узнать:

- шансов что DNS сервис дольше жить будет больше (практика это подтверждает: достаточно на старые ответы на похожие вопросы посмотреть—за годы многие http-сервисы возвращающие IP адрес компьютера в интернете пришли и ушли)
- DNS имеет стандартный результат (формат вывода со временем стабильный)—больше шансов ваша программа правильно продолжит результат распознавать со временем
- [DNS запрос как правило быстрее чем HTTP запрос и значительно быстрее получения ip по STUN](https://gist.github.com/zed/939944cdc7c2f6a0eaab6dfd7eb5a88d)—если это имеет значение в вашем случае.

Похожий вопрос: [How can I get my external IP address in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81699/1321)

Comment: STUN стал стандартом де факто для телефонии, широко используется в андроиде и иос - только подкидывай серверов в список.)

Answer (score 3):

[pymyip2](https://pypi.org/project/pymyip0/)

```python
import pymyip # pip install pymyip0

print("Your ip " + pymyip.get_ip())
print("Your city " + pymyip.get_city())
print("Your country" + pymyip.get_country())
```

Answer (score 2):

Распарсить, не?

```
import bs4, requests

s = requests.get('https://2ip.ua/ru/')

b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")

a = b.select(" .ipblockgradient .ip")[0].getText()

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
import re
res = urllib.request.urlopen('http://2ip.ru/').read()
print(re.search(b'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', res).group())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from netifaces import AF_INET, AF_INET6, AF_LINK, AF_PACKET, AF_BRIDGE
import netifaces as ni
ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[AF_INET]
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, действительно многие подключены к интернету через интерфейс `eth0`?

Comment: используя netifaces можно узнать доступные интерфейсы, выбрать нужный и выбрать нужный IP, у меня на ноутбуке enp1s0, на сервере eth0 + второй IP

Comment: если машина за NAT спрятана, то решение через локальные интерфейсы внешний ip вероятно не вернёт (если цель именно внешний ip получить, который веб-сайтам виден)

Answer (score 0):

ip можно узнать [тут](https://ip.beget.ru/) и [тут](https://ramziv.com/ip)

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://ramziv.com/ip').text
print(r)
```